# Power Automate "Add a row into a table", I am not able to detect my sharepoint excel file however can connect to one drive excel

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, excel-online

I am trying to import data from email to SharePoint file however I can perform this action only for my OneDrive excel files, my SharePoint is not getting detected. I can find my SharePoint through other actions
like "update file(SharePoint)" or "create file(SharePoint). my expectation is to connect to SharePoint excel file using "Add a row into a table" action. Please help how to resolve this issue?

I tried all alternatives but none of them is working, "Add a row into a table" will be an easy option for me however somehow my SharePoint its not getting detected.

Comment: Screenshots help ...!  A bit hard to help diagnose without them.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the 'Add a row into a table' action have you tried to enter the site url as a custom input?

In another thread a user could not select a site because he had many sites and that particular one was not on the list. Entering the site by URL works, but it's even better to use environment variables where possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharePoint online modern experience site, it should be shown under the Location drop down like:

[image]

If it is not showing here because you are using classic site or due to any other reason, you can select **Enter custom value** option and then manually enter your site URL like:

[image]

[image]